# Drop down menu variable not passed to eamil PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm new at php and I know this is simple but I can not figure what I've done wrong. No matter what I try I can't get the 'event' variable to pass into the email.

-HTML-

```
<div class="container">
<form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" action="this.php">
            <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <label for="event">What Kind of Event is it?</label><br>
                     <!--<select name="Event" tabindex="1">-->
                    <select class="form-control" id="inputEvent">
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
                <br>
                    <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" 
          id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Your Email">
            </div><br><br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="human" control-label>Are you human? 2 + 3 = 
                                                       ?</label><br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" 
                             name="human" placeholder="Your Answer?">
           </div>
            <br><br>
            <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"   
                                                      value="Filter">
        Send Message
    </button>
            </div>
        </form>        
</div>
```

this.php

```
 <?php
$event = $_POST['inputEvent'];
$email = check_input($_POST['inputEmail'], "Your E-mail Address");

Email: $email
Event: $event
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be confusing but you need to use the "name" attribute rather than the "id" attribute. Try changing your form to:

```
            <select class="form-control" name="inputEvent">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, but that didn't work. I still get nothing pasted for 'inputEvent.  I am only looking for one value for the drop down menu to be past. Nothing I try, posts the variable.  I can't even get echo to work. :(